# How to put the file compiled by gulp-compass into gulp's stream?

Tags: node.js, sass, minify, compass, gulp-compass

I am a newbie to gulp and gulp-compass. IMHO, gulp-compass doesn't work in the gulp's stream paradigm.

Normally, gulp's task should be something like:

```
gulp.src('path/to/src')
.pipe(doSth)
.pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/dist'));
```

But the following code works for gulp-compass:

```
gulp.src('') // <-Empty source is OK
.pipe(compass({
  css: 'path/to/dist/css' // <- This is the output dir
  scss: 'path/to/src/scss' // <- This is the input scss file glob
}));
// No dest is needed!
```

This results in my following problem.

```
|- dist
|- scss
    |- app.scss
|- css
    |- bootstrap.css
```

I want to use `gulp-compass` to compile `app.scss` into `app.css`, then bundle `app.css` with `bootstrap.css`, then minify and output as `app-release.css`.

I want to finish this task in **ONE** `gulp.task`.

```
function buildCss(inputStream) { // minify and output to dist.
    return inputStream
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}

gulp.task('css-build', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: 'css',
            sass: 'scss'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.src('css/*.css')); // <-- **HERE** 
    return buildCss(stream);
});
```

However, The compiled app.css file is not included in stream of **HERE**.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this problem using [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream).

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var scss = gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
        css: 'css',
        sass: 'scss'
    }));
    var css = gulp.src('css/bootstrap.css');
    var stream = merge(scss, css)
    .pipe(concat('app-release.css'));
    return buildCss(stream);
});
```